# How to get Sinatra to auto-reload the file after each change?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am using

```
# my_app.rb
load 'index.rb'
```

and start the sever like this

```
ruby my_app.rb
```

but it never reload any changes I made in index page.
Did I miss anything here?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

See the [Sinatra FAQ](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html),

["How do I make my Sinatra app reload on changes?"](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#reloading)

> First off, in-process code reloading in Ruby is hard and having a
>   solution that works for every scenario is technically impossible.
>
> Which is why we recommend you to do out-of-process reloading.
>
> First you need to install [rerun](https://github.com/alexch/rerun) if you haven’t already:
>
> ```
>  $ gem install rerun
> ```
>
> Now if you start your Sinatra app like this:
>
> ```
> $ ruby app.rb
> ```
>
> All you have to do for reloading is instead do this:
>
> ```
> $ rerun 'ruby app.rb'
> ```
>
> If you are for instance using rackup, instead do
>   the following:
>
> $ rerun 'rackup'
>
> You get the idea.
>
> If you still want in-process reloading, check out [`Sinatra::Reloader`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/reloader).

Comment: shotgun requires a minimal config.ru. If you don't have one already, create it and put "require './my_app'" (where my_app.rb is your ruby app) in it and you'll be set.

Comment: Small addition to for `rerun`. You are not limited with default options i.e. `rerun 'rackup'`. It's possible to run any server on any port. Here is example how to run Puma on port number 5678 — `rerun 'rackup -s puma -p 5678 app/sinatra/config.ru'`

Answer (score 45):

> gem install sinatra-reloader

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'
```

**Note**: it will reload only sinatra handlers (and, maybe some sinatra server configuration commands), but not custom files, which you have to reload manually.

**UPD after 9 years:** seems like it is already possible to reload other files using `also_reload`, `dont_reload` and `after_reload` -- https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/pull/1150

Comment: Hey @Nakilon, how would I go about re-loading such files manually? I am doing `require "./my-file"` without success

Comment: @kristianlm, `require` doesn't reload file, if it already was required. You `load` instead.

Comment: you are right. I have to re-save my `server.rb`, though, to get it to reload my external file. It doesn't check my external file alone, so I have to re-save my `sever.rb` every time I make a change to my external file. [shotgun](http://rubygems.org/gems/shotgun) seems to work better in this regard, but it also seems to re-load the database sessions.

Comment: Use the also_reload method to specify which files to reload:
`configure :development do |c|
  require 'sinatra/reloader'
  c.also_reload "./lib/*.rb"
  c.also_reload "./controllers/*.rb"  
  c.also_reload "./init/*.rb"
end`

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `rerun` gem.

```
gem install rerun
rerun 'ruby app.rb'
```

OR if you are using rackup

```
rerun 'rackup'
```

Answer (score 11):

gem install sinatra-reloader

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require "sinatra/reloader"

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Reloader

  get '/' do
    "Hello Testing1!"
  end
end
```

You may want to set environment variable to development and conditionally load the gem.

Answer (score 6):

When you run the application with [Passenger Standalone](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html), just create a `tmp/always_restart` file:

```
$ touch tmp/always_restart.txt
```

See Passenger [documentation](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_making_the_application_restart_after_each_request) for more info.

Answer (score 5):

I like the Shotgun gem. If you're using a modular Sinatra app and have a config.ru file it's easy to run.

```
shotgun config.ru
```

Check the gem out [here](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun). It's fairly straight forward and no configuration needed.

Comment: Shotgun is nice but isn't compatible with ruby 3+.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, I am using my [restart gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/restart) for this:

```
restart ruby my_app.rb
```

or, with rackup:

```
restart rackup
```

See [here](https://github.com/vais/restart) for more info, hope you find it useful.

Comment: the documentation states that it doesn't work on windows, i tried and it loads sinatra but doesn't reload on chenges

Answer (score 1):

You could use guard-rack. Lifted from an [article at dblock.org](http://code.dblock.org/watching-rack-application-changes-with-guard-rack):

Add this to your Gemfile:

```rb
group :development do
  gem "guard"
  gem "guard-bundler"
  gem "guard-rack"
end
```

Then, create a `Guardfile` at the root of your project with this content:

```rb
guard 'bundler' do
  watch('Gemfile')
end

guard 'rack' do
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch(%r{^(config|app|api)/.*})
end
```

Lastly, run Guard, like so: `bundle exec guard`, and `rackup` will reload every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you only change your templates sinatra will always rerender them if you set your environment to development:

```
ruby app.rb -e development
```