# Rack::Reloader not picking up changes

Tags: sinatra, rack

Consider this `config.ru` file:

```rb
require 'sinatra'

use Rack::Reloader, 0

get '/' do
  'hi'
end

run Sinatra::Application
```

I start it from the command line with `thin start`.  The application runs and shows `hi` when I hit `localhost:3000`.  If I now change `hi` to `hello`, save the file, and reload the page, the change does not appear:  the page still says `hi`.

Why does `Rack::Reloader` not work in this case?  Can I change anything to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [here](https://devver.wordpress.com/2009/12/21/making-rackreloader-work-with-sinatra/) for a detailed explanation of what's happening. Essentialy everytime your file is changed, `Rack::Reloader` re-requires it.

Unfortunately with Sinatra, if you redefine a route a second time (which is what happens when you re-require), sinatra ignores the new definition since `get '/' do end` is already defined!

What you will need to do is reset any defined routes you have as well:

```
# inside app.rb

require 'sinatra'
require 'rack'

configure :development do
    Sinatra::Application.reset!
    use Rack::Reloader
end

get '/' do
  'hi'
end
```

Note that sometimes it takes a few seconds (5s on my machine) for the changes to be reloaded and I recommend you take a [look at the alternatives here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247125/how-to-get-sinatra-to-auto-reload-the-file-after-each-change)