# Browsers do not show the latest changes (Sinatra, Ruby, ATOM)

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, safari, sinatra, atom-editor

I am building a Sinatra (ruby) application by using ATOM- editor.
After sometime Safari and Chrome do not show the latest html/erb changes what i make in Atom. To lunch the app I am using ruby "filename".rb and shotgun "filename".rb
I tried "clear browser data" Sometimes it works sometimes not.
Could you please give me an advice what to do in case of this error?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to  require "sinatra/reloader"  in order for the application to change along with changes made in Atom. Here are the docs: http://sinatrarb.com/contrib/reloader

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Sinatra to auto-reload the file after each change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247125/how-to-get-sinatra-to-auto-reload-the-file-after-each-change)

Comment: Thank you @VIktor, but It worked before i updated some application on my laptop. I have had this issue since then. I added sinatra/reloader to my gem file but the issue is not resolved. I have just modified the erb/html file, so added a <p> and it appeared in my browser, but CSS modification does not work.

Comment: Are changes visible in other browsers ?

Comment: @VIktor ,I use Chrome and Safari. I can see the changes by modifying of the erb/html file. But the result is different in the browsers. :(